# how to resolve this transaction submission error of MintToken with Mesh

Tags: cardano-cli, nft, minting, blockfrost, mesh

I am Facing this error while transaction submission.
`""transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (PPViewHashesDontMatch (SJust (SafeHash \"268fc512be7cdc13c5e3da75d2888a5790c01173b32a38b4da2972a3b0059ee2\")) (SJust (SafeHash \"47120f8f4cf7f65759c1a535d34e593e271bcd69fb9719359f8ec23cd73f0221\"))))])""`
I am following the mesh api tutorial https://meshjs.dev/apis/transaction/smart-contract#plutusminting
The code is exact same as given in tutorial, but i am stuck at this error for so long. For safe side i am also pasting the code here. Kindly suggest a solution for it, will be very helpful for me.
Thanks in Advance

````
import { AssetMetadata, Mint, Action, PlutusScript } from '@meshsdk/core';

const script: PlutusScript = {
  code: plutusMintingScriptCbor,
  version: 'V2',
};

const redeemer: Partial<Action> = {
  tag: 'MINT',
};

const tx = new Transaction({ initiator: wallet });

// define asset#1 metadata
const assetMetadata1: AssetMetadata = {
  "name": "Mesh Token",
  "image": "ipfs://QmRzicpReutwCkM6aotuKjErFCUD213DpwPq6ByuzMJaua",
  "mediaType": "image/jpg",
  "description": "This NFT is minted by Mesh (https://meshjs.dev/)."
};
const asset1: Mint = {
  assetName: 'MeshToken',
  assetQuantity: '1',
  metadata: assetMetadata1,
  label: '721',
  recipient: 'addr_test1vpvx0sacufuypa2k4sngk7q40zc5c4npl337uusdh64kv0c7e4cxr',
};
tx.mintAsset(
  script,
  asset1,
  redeemer,
);

const unsignedTx = await tx.build();
const signedTx = await wallet.signTx(unsignedTx);
const txHash = await wallet.submitTx(signedTx);```
````

Answer (score 0):

The code you are seeing is returned directly from the node.

`PPViewHashesDontMatch` means that the protocol parameters hash does not match what is on-chain.

Are you sure you are using the latest version of Mesh?

Comment: yes, I have meshsdk/core 1.3.0 and meshsdk/react 1.1.3 version. And both of these are latest one

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the redeemer you are passing is correct?

Comment: Yes, the redeemer here is just a formality as the script is always true script. Also i copied the redeemer format from the tutorial link given.

Answer (score 0):

I been dealing with this problem using Lucid for building the transactions.

When the framework create the transactions it was using wrong protocols parameters.

There is a field in the body of the transaction, called script_data_hash.

This field need to be filled before submitting the transaction.

Script data hash is a hash related with the redeemers of the transactions, the datums and the cost model (protocol parameters)

For example in Lucid, I fixed it updating the cost models and calculating all again:

```
const redeemers = witness_set_NEW_VERISON.redeemers();
const datums = witness_set_NEW_VERISON.plutus_data();
const costModels_NEW_VERISON = createCostModels_NEW_VERISON(protocolParameters.costModels);
const scriptHash = hash_script_data(redeemers!, costModels_NEW_VERISON, datums);
body.set_script_data_hash(C.ScriptDataHash.from_bytes(scriptHash.to_bytes()));
```

The error you are receiving is that the set_script_data_hash in the body is not matching the one that is calculated in the node when trying to validate the transaction.

Check where you initialize:

```
const tx = new Transaction({ initiator: wallet });
```

If there is a way to set manually the protocol parameters or the cost model.

Comment: Yes but in mesh library, there is no such variable to set the protocol parameters, It just create, build and sign the transmission with it function only. So how can i check these in Mesh library